# Post paid cancelable hotel in Paris?

Tags: hotels, paris

Is there a hotel in Paris (preferably close to La-Defense) that allows reservations without payment and does not charge a fee for cancellation or change of dates?

I need to get a hotel reservation for two weeks to get my schengen visa and once it's confirmed I pay for the hotel and/or possible adjust the dates once I get my flights and everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most hotels listed in [booking.com](http://www.booking.com) are of this type. You can book a hotel and later cancel the booking without any fee or charges. The site is very reliable. For your particular case, you may book [this hotel](http://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/campanile-nanterre.en-gb.html?sid=64e3fdb99a2d982d7cd8fa67eacab645;dcid=4;checkin=2014-09-05;checkout=2014-09-06;ucfs=1;srfid=b9ceb841404da0a80d6e666d9a870fa020252a78X3).

Comment: Do they charge my cc in EUR or USD? I'm concerned about the forex charges.

Comment: If you're going to hold the reservation, then cancel later, why do you care what they'd charge at checkin when you won't be ever checking in?

Comment: For no-deposit, free cancellation hotels the website doesn't charge you. It only asks for your credit card number to secure reservation. The amount is charged at the hotel in local currency (EUR for this hotel).

Comment: Most likely I will change the dates. Either choose the same hotel or change it completely.

Comment: I was once in the same situation, and reserved a hotel in Zürich without actually giving them my credit card info.